# Error LavaMoat - property “Reflect” of globalThis is inaccessible under scuttling mode

Tags: metamask

Although I have set ScuttleGlobalThis.enable to false in runtime-lavamoat.js still I get this error.
I’m using MetaMask snap and trying to use fetch to call an external API.
I tried rebuilding MetaMask flask in dev mode in order to turn scuttleGlobalThis off however I always get the error.

I used this command

```
yarn start --build-type flask
```

to run metamask flask and generate the dist file. and then I added the extension to my chrome extension.
I'm using metamask snap to call and external API using global fetch however I get the following error:

```
Error LavaMoat - property “Reflect” of globalThis is inaccessible under scuttling mode
```